# InfluxDB - How to get start timestamp of alternating series

Tags: select, query, influx-db

I have these data series in an influx database, alternating between 0 and 1.

```
2018-10-02T07:12:00Z 0
2018-10-02T07:15:00Z 0
2018-10-02T07:18:00Z 0
2018-10-02T07:21:00Z 0
2018-10-02T07:24:00Z 0
2018-10-02T07:27:00Z 1
2018-10-02T07:30:00Z 1
2018-10-02T07:33:00Z 1
2018-10-02T07:36:00Z 1
2018-10-02T07:39:00Z 1
2018-10-02T07:42:00Z 1
2018-10-02T07:45:00Z 1
2018-10-02T07:48:00Z 1
2018-10-02T07:51:00Z 1
2018-10-02T07:54:00Z 1
2018-10-02T07:57:00Z 1
2018-10-02T08:00:00Z 1
2018-10-02T08:03:00Z 0
2018-10-02T08:06:00Z 0
2018-10-02T08:09:00Z 0
2018-10-02T08:12:00Z 0
2018-10-02T08:15:00Z 0
2018-10-02T08:18:00Z 0
2018-10-02T08:21:00Z 0
2018-10-02T08:24:00Z 1
2018-10-02T08:27:00Z 1
2018-10-02T08:30:00Z 1
2018-10-02T08:33:00Z 1
2018-10-02T08:36:00Z 1
2018-10-02T08:39:00Z 1
2018-10-02T08:42:00Z 1
```

How do I get the first timestamp from the alternating to 0 and to 1? I want to have the timestamp, when the value changes to 0 and when it changes to 1. The result I am expecting should look like this:

```
2018-10-02T08:03:00Z 0
2018-10-02T08:24:00Z 1
```

Somebody can push me in the right direction? I am totally stuck.